# Spark Scala Dynamic column selection from DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-ml

I have a DataFrame which have different type of columns. Among those column, i need to retrieve specific column from that DataFrame.
Hard coded DataFrame select statement will be like this:

```
val logRegrDF = myDF.select(myDF("LEBEL_COLUMN").as("label"),
col("FEATURE_COL1"), col("FEATURE_COL2"), col("FEATURE_COL3"), col("FEATURE_COL4"))
```

Where LEBEL_COLUMN and FEATURE_COLs will be dynamic.
I have Array or Seq for those FEATURE Columns like this:

```
val FEATURE_COL_ARR = Array("FEATURE_COL1","FEATURE_COL2","FEATURE_COL3","FEATURE_COL4")
```

I need to use this Array of column collection with that SELECT statement in the 2nd part.
In the select, 1st column will be one (LABEL_COLUMN) and rest will be dynamic list.

Can you please help me to make the select statement working in SCALA.

**Note:**
The sample code given bellow is working, but i need to add column array in the 2nd part of the SELECT

```
val colNames = FEATURE_COL_ARR.map(name => col(name))
val logRegrDF = myDF.select(colNames:_*)  // it is not the requirement
```

I am thinking for 2nd part code will be like this, but it is not working:

```
val logRegrDF = myDF.select(myDF("LEBEL_COLUMN").as("label"), colNames:_*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I hope this is what you are looking for

```
val allColumnsArr = "LEBEL_COLUMN" +: FEATURE_COL_ARR
result.select("LEBEL_COLUMN", allColumnsArr: _*)
  .withColumnRenamed("LEBEL_COLUMN", "label")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Shankar, Thanks a lot.
Though your given suggestion is not working, but i got idea from your suggestion and solved the issue by this way
    val allColumnsArr = "LEBEL_COLUMN" +: FEATURE_COLUMNS
    val colNames = allColumnsArr.map(name => col(name)) 
    myDF.select(colNames:_*).withColumnRenamed("LEBEL_COLUMN", "label")

Comment: Updated the answer, please check. You don't need to columns, the strings are also accepted as arguments.

Comment: Yes this works.
 
    result.select("LEBEL_COLUMN", FEATURE_COL_ARR: _*) .withColumnRenamed("LEBEL_COLUMN", "label")

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @Shankar.

Though your given suggestion is not working, but i got an idea from your suggestion and solved the issue by this way

```
val allColumnsArr = "LEBEL_COLUMN" +: FEATURE_COL_ARR
val colNames = allColumnsArr.map(name => col(name)) 
myDF.select(colNames:_*).withColumnRenamed("LEBEL_COLUMN", "label")
```

Also this way without creating DataFrame column:

```
result.select(LEBEL_COLUMN, FEATURE_COL_ARR: _*) .withColumnRenamed(LEBEL_COLUMN, "label")
```

Comment: result.select("LEBEL_COLUMN", FEATURE_COL_ARR: _*)
  .withColumnRenamed("LEBEL_COLUMN", "label")

It woks this way also.